# Showing that #SAT is NP-hard

Tags: computational-complexity

I need some hints to solve the following problem. (from *Complexity and cryptography by Talbot and Welsh*, chapter 3, exercise 3.6)

> Let #SAT be the function, mapping Boolean formulae in CNF to $\mathbb
>  Z^+$ defined
>
> $\text{#SAT}(f) = |\{a \in \{0, 1\}^n | f (a) = 1\}|$
>
> Show that #SAT is NP-hard.

Comment: Could you add the definition of NP you're using and whether you've proven anything else is NP-hard?

Comment: Hint: Formula is satisfiable if and only if has at least one satisfying assignment.

Comment: @PeterKošinár: Thanks, but I see no relevance between your hint which is a basic concept and the problem I am trying to solve. Plus that, not iff there's at least one satisfying assignment, but iff there's at least one satisfying **truth** assignment.

Comment: Let's expand the hint a bit: In order to show that #SAT is NP-hard, it suffices to show that it is at least as difficult as another, already-known-to-be-NP-hard problem. In this case, SAT (known to be NP-complete) is a natural choice for this "other" problem. My hint pointed out the (yes, trivial) connection between SAT which asks "is the formula satisfiable" and #SAT which asks "how many satisfying assignments does the formula have".

Comment: @PeterKošinár: Got it, thank your for your further explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Though it talks about a different NP-hard problem, [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/379921/confusion-related-to-the-definition-of-np-problems/380481#380481) might be of help. Essentially, you need to show that (1) given a proposed satisfying solution $a$, you can *verify* its correctness in time polynomial in its length using a deterministic Turing Machine or, equivalently, that (2) you can *find* a satisfying solution in poly time using a nondeterministic TM.